Formula for $TE(M,0,N)$ mode of microwave cavity
I am interested in the general formula for the magnetic and electric field of a TE mode of a 3D microwave cavity.
In Pozar's Microwave Engineering Book, the formulas for the fields of a 3D cavity with modes of $TE (1,0,l)$ are provided as:
\begin{align*}
E_y &= E_0 \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\ell \pi z}{d}\right), \\
H_x &= -\frac{j E_0}{Z_{TE}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\ell \pi z}{d}\right), \\
H_z &= \frac{j \pi E_0}{k \eta a} \cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\ell \pi z}{d}\right),
\end{align*}
I am interested in modes $TE (m,0,l)$. Has this been solved before and I can just take a formula from a textbook? Or do I need to go through and try to solve the system myself?

go ahead and solve it for yourself, it is a good exercise; $TM_{mo\ell}$ is just as easy to find as the $TE_{10\ell}$, or any of the $TE-TN_{mn\ell}$ modes, but if you are stuck then come back with that problem how & why.

These are a solution of Maxwell equation in a cavity with metal boundary condition at the boarders. The solutions are waves in vacuum or homogeneous material with dielectric constant. In this case you have standing waves when adding waves going forward and backward

In Pozar's book the solution is well explained, by the way
